# Validação de variável HTML

Tags: javascript, html, variáveis

Boa tarde pessoal, tudo bem?

Recebi um projeto interno e não estou conseguindo finalizar.

Possuo esse trecho de uma página HTML:

```
    <span style='font-size:9.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:black>'>
    Apresente este QRCode no terminal de autoatendumento. Ele também está anexo. <BR>
    Identifique-se na <b><span style=font-size:11.0pt;>%%nomePortaria%%</b>, conforme ilustração abaixo.
    </span></span></p>
```

Logo abaixo desse trecho, é exibido um gif da portaria selecionada através do código abaixo:

```
    <p align=center>
    <img name="imagem1" width=360 height=208>
    </p>
```

A questão é: Eu preciso que o gif seja alterado de acordo com o parâmetro passado na variável %%nomePortaria%%. 
Eu criei esse código bem simples para ver se funcionaria, mas não rolou...

```
<script>
function srcImage(path) {
    document.imagem1.src = path;
}

window.onload = function() {

    if(%%nomePortaria%%  == 1){
        srcImage('85.gif');
    } 
    else if(%%nomePortaria%% == 2){
        srcImage('86.gif');
    }
    else{
        srcImage('84.gif);
    }
}   
</script>
```

As imagens estão na mesma pasta do arquivo, apenas para teste... futuramente, irei alterar os caminhos para uma url das imagens corretas.

Valeu galera!

Comment: Veja que essa variável está vindo de um backend, correto?

Comment: Isso... é que na verdade eu não tenho acesso ao backend... apenas me passaram esse código e pediram pra fazer isso... :/

Answer (score 0):

Oi, Arildo. 
Não entendi muito bem o escopo do que você quer, mas só com HTML você não resolve. O script que você declarou é JavaScript e é nele que você tem que operar. Você var precisar ter uma variável para tratar no IF. Vai precisar também de algum jeito de alterar a variável dinamicamente. O que você pensou?

```
<script type="javascript">
var nomePortaria = "1";
function srcImage(path) {
    document.imagem1.src = path;
}

window.onload = function() {

    if(nomePortaria  == 1){
        srcImage('85.gif');
    } 
    else if(nomePortaria == 2){
        srcImage('86.gif');
    }
    else{
        srcImage('84.gif);
    }
}   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é que estás a misturar código `backend` com `javascript.`

Uma solução, seria `forçar` essa variável que vem do `backend` ser transformada em uma variável `javascript`.

Coloque essa linha de `script` acima da importação do código que estás a criar.

```
<script> var nomePortaria = %%nomePortaria%% </script>
```

E o seu script de validação:

```
<script>
function srcImage(path) {
    document.imagem1.src = path;
}

window.onload = function() {

    if(nomePortaria  == 1){
        srcImage('85.gif');
    } 
    else if(nomePortaria == 2){
        srcImage('86.gif');
    }
    else{
        srcImage('84.gif);
    }
}   
</script>
```

Lembre-se de colocar o `script` de validação abaixo do script em que criamos a variável.